# How to put focus on a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, focus

How do I put focus on a textbox with JavaScript(Or jQuery)?

I have a textbox on a page and after the user presses the enter key, the textbox loses focus. (Keep in mind that no post occurs, the page does not refresh)

I want to be able set the focus back inside of the textbox through javascript so that the user can continue typing and doesn't have to click on anything.

I tried adding the following code after the users has pressed the enter key:

```
$(".focus").focus();
```

The code for my textbox:

```
<input type="text" class="focus" />
```

but alas, the cursor does not appear inside of the textbox and the user still has to click to continue typing.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: How exactly did you add the focus() code after the user pressed Enter?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply the `focus` code to the `input`, if the page hasn't loaded or the `DOM` isn't ready when the code runs, then there's no `input` yet to `focus` on..

So you have to check that the DOM is loaded, like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".focus").focus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7aUS/

You can also include the code at the bottom of the page, before the `</body>` tag, so that it loads right after all your HTML.

**note**: If you're running this in jsfiddle, by default your code is run on page load. When using JQuery, it automatically wraps it in this code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
     //your code here
});
```

## EDIT:

In that case, [meetamit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13225679/276250) is very helpful, I think you're looking for this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".focus").focus();
    $(".focus").on('keydown', function(event) {
        if(event.which == 13) {// Enter key pressed
            $this = $(this);
            $this.focus();
            var value = $this.val();
            $this.val(''); /* clear the field */
            // do stuff with the value
        }
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7aUS/1/

Answer (score 1):

Why does pressing the enter key take away the focus from the field? (I couldn't reproduce it.) It might suggest that there's a hidden problem still. Maybe not. If not, this might help:

```
$(".focus").on('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13) {// Enter key pressed
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

​

Comment: This is **a** solution, although not very elegant IMO. The enter key may be needed for something else later. `preventDefault()` on something as necessary as the `enter` key should be the absolute last resort. Maybe not even that.

Comment: @Abhilash This only prevents default IN the specified field, everywhere else it works as expected.